# How to know the area of the rectangles is less than or greater than the integral for an integral test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, intuition

I am currently studying the integral test for infinite series, but I am confused by the pictures used in the integral tests to show that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, but $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

The explanation for the divergence of $\frac{1}{n}$ uses [this picture of $\frac{1}{x}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLuOF.png) to show that $\sum \frac{1}{n} \geq \int \frac{1}{x} dx$, so that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges. Now, for the convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ [this picture of $\frac{1}{x^2}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ghsc.png) is used to show $\sum \frac{1}{n^2} \leq 1 + \int \frac{1}{x} dx$. However, in the first picture the rectangles are drawn from the upper left corner, while the upper right corner is used in the second picture. If we were to draw the rectangles from the left corner, the rectangles would be shifted to the left by 1 so that all recantgles are less than the integral at each point (i think)

So, my question is how to decide what corner to use to be able to determine whether the value of the integral will be less than or greater than the sum of the rectangles.

Comment: To show that it diverges, you want an underestimate to be infinity. To show that it converges, you want an overestimate to be finite.

Comment: That sounds logical, thank you! I was under the assumption that corner should always be the same. I will accept the proposed answer to close this question, but your reply helped me as well.

Comment: If you don't already know, you should figure out the following: For an underestimate, if the function is strictly increasing (resp decreasing), do we want to use the left-corner rectangles or the right-corner rectangles.

Comment: I figure we should use the right corner for an increasing function, as the graph will lie below the the 'top' of the rectangle

Comment: Yup. In general for the integral test, where you're integrating over the real line, so the function has to converge to 0 for the integral to exist, which means we're generally dealing with a decreasing function. Hence Ricky's solution applies in this specific case (but otherwise not for any general function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to prove by the comparison test.

Rectangles drawn with the upper left corner on the curve result in a sum that is **greater than** the integral, so if the integral diverges, the sum also diverges. But if the integral converges, no information on the sum is obtained.

Rectangles drawn with the upper right corner on the curve result in a sum that is **less than** the integral, so if the integral converges, the sum also converges. But if the integral diverges, no information on the sum is obtained.

Comment: Thank you. That made it very clear to me